# Using preventDefault in Elm

Tags: elm

How do I use preventDefault in elm? Say on a keyboard event:

```
keyDown keyCode model =
    case keyCode of

        13 -> -- Enter key
            model
```

if we don't want the default behaviour?

[Html.Events](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/latest/) has methods for it, but I don't understand how to use it in practice.

Comment: http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/elm-html/4.0.0/Html-Events#Options

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**This answer is obsolete with Elm 0.19**

Learn how to use `Html.Events.on`, then it becomes obvious.

```elm
myInput =
  input
    [ on "keydown" (Json.map KeyInput keyCode)]
    []
```

becomes...

```elm
myInputWithOptions =
  input
    [ onWithOptions "keydown" options (Json.map KeyInput keyCode)]
    []

options =
  { stopPropagation = True
  , preventDefault = True
  }
```

(Here, message constructor `KeyInput`
is defined as: `type Msg = KeyInput Int`)

Comment: Seems like this doesn't exist in elm anymore.

Answer (score 6):

@Tosh has shown how to stop event propagation and prevent default behaviour in his answer.

If your specific case is to prevent default behaviour only on Enter but not on any other keys, this is currently not possible in Elm—you'll have to resort to Ports and JS.

Comment: Looks like there's a workaround now for conditionally calling preventDefault: https://github.com/elm/virtual-dom/issues/18#issuecomment-273403774

Answer (score 2):

You can now use the library [elm-community/html-extra](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/html-extra/3.4.0/Html-Events-Extra) for that, it provides you the `onClickPreventDefault` and `onClickStopPropagation` functions.

Comment: This is a long time ago, but I actually ended up implementing it in the same way. And it works.